# Soft Margin constraints in SVM

Tags: machine-learning, classification, svm

I have understood the constraints of Hard Margin SVM but stuck at Soft Margin SVM.

The Objective Function along with constraints of Soft Margin SVM is given below.[image]

such that [image: [1]]
 and
 [image]

The slack variable represents how far away is a point from the correct hyperplane.

My question is how did we obtain the first constraint?
Can't the optimization problem be solved without the first constraint?

Comment: The part between parenthesis in the 1st constraint is proportional to the (signed) distance to the separating hyperplane. Multiplying by y \in {0,1} makes it always positive when correct. This should be high, hence the \geq 1 - \eps. Find a good explanation in Tishbirani's the elements of statistical learning